# How do I insert a List of value into an Enumerable?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, enumerable

I have to look if the first element in my IEnumerable is equal to a certain value and if so I have to update it to a new List

I'm trying to use something like that

```
if (sequence.First().Equals(value))
        {

            return newValues.Prepend(sequence.Skip(1));

        }
```

because I must be the most generic possible but when I try to test this call it just return null

Comment: IEnumerable does not allow modification.

Comment: Use something like `newValues.Concat(sequence.Skip(1))` (Both `Concat` and `Skip` are Linq extension methods; if something is unclear, the documentation is at your fingertips)

Comment: can I rephrase? you want to test a sequence against a value, and if the first item in the sequence is a match, you want to append the *rest* of the sequence to a *separate* list - otherwise ... not?

Comment: yes, I need to append the newList to the old one if the condition is true

Comment: @MattiaCaruso, your question explains that you want to append the old list to the new list. However, now you are saying that you want to append the new list to the old one. Which one ist it now? It cannot be both...

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify `IEnumerable`. But you could use this approach:

```
// your sample:
IEnumerable<int> sequence = new[] {2, 5, 1};
int value = 2;
IEnumerable<int> newValues = new[] {1, 2, 3};

if (sequence.First() == value)
    return newValues.Concat(sequence.Skip(1)).ToList()
else
    return sequence.ToList();
```

Comment: @elgonzo: not needed. But since the source was an array i thought the result should be the same type. Otherwise you would generate this sequence everytime you'd use it.

Comment: I'm trying this : collection = newValues.Concat((sequence.Skip(1).ToList())) as List<T>; because my function return a List <T> but the test keep failing ( I create a list with the values I expect to be returned and check them with the return value)

Comment: @MattiaCaruso: if you need a list use `ToList` as here: `newValues.Concat(sequence.Skip(1)).ToList()`. Shown in my answer